# Facebook connect work fro test user but not with other users

Tags: ios, facebook

I switch my app in the Facebook developper web site to live and I am still unable to connect with "normal" FB accounts using Facebook connect except for defined test users (or developper account). It seems it continues to behave the same way as if it still not live.
My app just use standard permission (public_profile) which doesn't need a review from FB according to FB.

I got the following error when trying with a "normal" FB account:
The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: The proxied app is not already installed

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

go to **Status & Review** in your app page and

```
Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?
```

make it Yes.

Then you can login with all users.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I did before noticing this behaviour.

Comment: If this is the solution then please mark it as an answer, thus other can get help from it.

Comment: No it doesn't solve the issue. I am currently discussing this directly with Facebook and I will post the solution as soon as it will be solved.

Comment: FB support doesn't figure out why using iOS social SDK it request more permissions than the ones giving as parameter and advice to use FB SDK instead. I reimplement it and no more issues and